# How to screenshot the current webpage in an IE extension

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-extension, webpage-screenshot

So far, we've accomplished taking a screenshot of the current page with extensions for Firefox, Safari and Chrome - which were all more or less easy. However there doesn't seem to be any official documentation for extension development for IE at all, and out of unofficial documentation haven't found anything related to taking screenshots.

Is this even possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Comment: any specific version of IE required, or do you need it to work in all versions?

Comment: There is no reason for writing an IE extension for this. When OneNote is installed, you can just press Win+S to capture anything.